# VBA CreateObject versus Type Library References

Tags: vba, com, atl, late-binding

I have build a COM object via ATL, to use compiled C++ in VBA. My type library is (say) "MyObjLib", and the object is "MyObj".

If I use the Object Browser in VBA, all looks good: it shows me the Library as MyObjLib, and within that I see a class MyObj as a member of the library.

If, in VBA, I include this library through the References menu, I can write:

```
Dim obj as MyObj
Set obj = new MyObj
```

and it all works fine. However if I try:

```
Dim obj as Object
Set obj = CreateObject("MyObjLib.MyObj")
```

it fails with "Runtime Error 429: ActiveX component can't create object."

This is unfortunate as I now want to use the COM object from Python. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Check bitness of python vs bitness of your COM dll (32bit vs 64bit). Otherwise check the "progid" ("MyObjLib.MyObj") is indeed what's ATL registers. Technically it can be different. Also, use Procmon from sysinternals to monitor registry calls (filter on exe).

Comment: Is that all from VBA where it is failing the second time? I ask, because if it's all VBA, then it won't be a bitness issue, but probably something to do with the ProgID. In your first example, it's got nothing to do with the ProgID. It can create the object from the CLSID in the typelib. In the second example, it has to look up the CLSID from the ProgID. Assuming the second is VBA too, then as Simon says, look at ProgID--that it is there. And, also that the CLSID matches what is in the TypeLib.

Comment: If the second example IS NOT VBA, then actually put it in VBA and test it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I spent some time searching my C++ code for the ProgId. Then I stumbled across another SO answer, about someone who had left the ProgId field blank in the ATL Simple COM object Wizard ... which is exactly what I had done! Hence I had never registered the ProgId for the class (and hence no entry in HKCR in the Registy).

I created another project using the Wizard, this time entering a ProgID and copied the syntax from the .rgs file in the new project to my existing one.

Hey presto, CreateObject() works fine now.